# integral with disks

Tags: calculus

We are looking for the volume of the space between $y=\frac{-1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}$ and $y=x$ as rotated about the x-axis. I used the disk/washer method ($\pi r^2$) and broke it up into 3 pieces. I notice that there is a bit of overlap under the x-axis, so I have excluded it in my computation. Please see the attached picture for a more detailed view. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCvm4.jpg)

$\pi (\int_{-2}^0 [(-1/2)x+(3/2)]^2)dx+\pi(\int_0^1[(-1/2)x+(3/2)]^2-[x]^2)dx+\pi\int_1^3(x^2-[(-1/2)x+(3/2)]^2-[x]^2)dx=$
$\frac{-\pi}{4}\int_0^{-2}(x^2-6x+9)dx+\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1(x^2-6x+9)dx+\frac{\pi}{4}\int_1^3(3x^2+6x-x)dx=$

$\frac{\pi}{4}[(-\frac{x^3}{3}+3x^2-9x)_0^{-2}+(-x^3-3x^2+9x)_0^1+(x^3+3x^2-9x)_1^3]=$

$\frac{\pi}{4}[8/3+12+18-1+3+9+27+27-27-1-3+9]=$

$\frac{\pi}{4}[8/3+73]=$

$\frac{\pi}{4}(227/3)=$

$59.42846...$

Comment: Hi @nessa, unfortunately this question will be deleted unless you try to write down your question on this site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you must type your question and your attempt. Here is quick reference that will help you type your math. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also, if you indicate how you got the wrong answer, someone will undoubtedly be able to point to the exact spot where you went astray, and what ought to have been done instead.

Comment: On the one hand, your question may be reasonably regarded as a high quality question, since you clearly showed good work on the problem.  On the other hand, as others responses have indicated, your question needs to be improved in two ways before you can get help: [1] Please edit your question to state, up front, the exact wording of the problem that was assigned to you. [2] Please remove the posted image from the question, and instead edit your question by using [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to format the corresponding math.

Comment: You forgot to mention in your post that $-2 \leq x \leq 3$

Answer (score 2):

You split up the integral into three parts and these parts should be
$$ \pi \int_{-2}^{0}\left(\frac{-x}{2}+\frac 3 2\right)^2dx$$
$$\pi \int_{0}^1\left(\frac{-x}{2}+\frac 3 2\right)^2 - x^2dx$$
$$\pi \int_{1}^3 x^2 - \left(\frac{-x}{2}+\frac 3 2\right)^2dx$$
Notice that your third term has an extra $-x^2$ inside the integral which shouldn't be there, I guess that's a typo.

The way you calculate the first term is quite odd (why switch the bounds of the integral ?) but looks mostly fine.

The main problem is the computation of the second term since you drop the $-x^2$ inside the integral instead of what you wrote you should have

\begin{align}
\pi \int_{0}^1\left(\frac{-x}{2}+\frac 3 2\right)^2 - x^2dx &= \frac \pi 4 \int_{0}^1(-x + 3)^2 - 4x^2dx \\
&=\frac \pi 4 \int_{0}^1x^2 - 6x + 9 - 4x^2dx\\ 
&= \frac \pi 4 \int_{0}^1 -3x^2 - 6x + 9dx
\end{align}

For the third term you shouldn't obtain $3x^2+6x-x$ inside the integral rather you should have $3x^2 + 6x - 9$.